# Add layers of abstraction, or work in a single table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization

I am writing a cron script that will routinely go through rows in a specific table, parse the text, and then generate system-based tags for use in other operations.

This table is the life-blood of our site, and is quite large - and I am wondering if it is better to have the cron script work directly with this table, or syphon the text to be parsed off to another table, with which my cron script can safely work.

Here's a diagram of my thoughts:

Option 1:

```
Table 1: "blogs"
Table 2: "blog tags"

** cron script 'scrapes' the blogs table, marks each scraped blog to prevent duplicate scrapes, and then puts tags in the blog tags table
```

Option 2

```
Table 1: "blogs"
Table 2: "blogs to be parsed"
Table 3: "blog tags"

** when blogs are posted, some of their text and metadata is also inserted into "blogs to be parsed", which is the only table the cron script will have to then deal with.
```

Is there a performance / safety benefit for adding a layer of abstraction like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any benefit to the extra table unless you are worried your script will accidentally mess up data in the blogs table. Since this is a read only operation, you'd have serious bug for that to happen. Using the original table also means you are using the indexes defined there, so it should be fast.

You are just reading rows and setting a flag. Your blog engine is doing way more with the same table.

**Edit**

If you are worrying about the flag when updating the table, address that. Create a table with a foreign key to blogs, and a bit that says updated. Now you don't do any writes to the blog table in the cron job. Reads don't require any locks whatsoever.

However, unless the blog table is being hit hundreds of times per second, the update is so fast it will be imperceptible. As long as you are using innodb or a storage engine that supports row level locking, you are good.

Also make sure you do your updates at midnight when there is low traffic

Comment: true...I guess that was part of the worry. setting flag requires updating potentially many rows in the table (if many blogs are parsed at once)

Comment: smart...maybe the layer of abstraction simply happens with the organization aspect of the operation, vs the content

Comment: @jonnietheblack If it makes your life easier do it. But I wouldn't add the extra complexity for performance reasons alone. Remember, as paul said, whenever a blog gets updated, the extra table must be updated at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a good idea so long as you're not expecting your inserted data to have a high quantity of variability.  To clarify, if the data to be parsed can be inserted into the "to parse" table and you can forget about it, that's great; however, if you're expecting a lot of edits to the data, updating the "to be parsed" table on edits to the main table can be a big hassle, particularly because you're potentially keeping a lock on that table from your cron job.

What might make more sense is to have your cron job do data-based (recent) replication to the secondary table, then parse from there.  In that way, your cron job only locks the main table for as long as it takes to query all the recent updates (and that can be minimized by having the cron job run more frequently), then the recent updates get copied to the secondary table, where your cron job can have exclusive access without worrying about contention.

Comment: Do you mean the layer of abstraction? and by variability, do you mean, hoping it won't change much in the future?

Comment: Oh, sorry - and why is it a good idea? Is it actually safer, or better performance?

Comment: Does he actually need to lock the blogs table for the cronjob?

Comment: @johnnietheblack: yes, yes, and it's a good idea because it's both safer and can provide better performance (no contention on the main table).

Comment: another benefit of having a secondary table is scalability, maybe. for example, if i need to run more processes on the blogs later, they would be available here....though maybe, again, those processes could all take place in the main blogs table